# Inkscape .92 - Calligraphy Tool Problem

Tags: inkscape, calligraphy

I have done cartooning in Flash for many years, and my resolution for 2017 is to go Open Source as much as possible.  I downloaded InkScape 0.92  (Windows 10) . . . and I like it so far.

However, when I use the Calligraphy tool and my OLD wacom tablet . . . Whenever I draw intersecting lines with the tool is causes an artifact at the intersection.

Are other people seeing this?  I am trying to narrow down if it's a bug, my tablet, the OS, my graphics card, or InkScape.

[image: Inkscape 0.92 - Calligraphy Tool Issue]

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably enabled "lightness tracing", a setting which modifies the stroke width depending on the current color under your cursor. Disable the setting to avoid the thicker stroke around intersections.

[image: lightness tracing]

Comment: Thanks Socowi. This seems to remove the intersection problem, but it seems to remove the pressure sensitivity of my wacom pen.  It's odd because the line thickness seems to respond to speed only, pressure on the tips of the pen doesn't seem to do much no matter what settings I use.  (Even if I choose the pressure sensitivity icon.) Is it time for a new drawing tablet perhaps? Thanks again.

Comment: I think I found the answer with a quick google search.

Inscape->Edit->Input Devices

This allowed me to enable the tablet as an input device.  Problem solved.  Thanks again Socowi!

Comment: Your welcome. I'm glad I could help. Please accept the answer to mark your question as resolved.